# Collectors.toMap() keyMapper

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a `List<UserMeal>`collection, where UserMeal has:

```
public class UserMeal {
 private final LocalDateTime dateTime;
 private final int calories;

 public UserMeal(LocalDateTime dateTime, int calories) {
     this.dateTime = dateTime;
     this.calories = calories;
 }

 public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
     return dateTime;
 }

 public int getCalories() {
     return calories;
 }
}
```

I need to convert it into `Map<LocalDate, Integer>`.

The key of the map must be the `dateTime` (converted to `LocalDate`) of the UserMeal item in the collection.

And the value of the map has to be sum of `calories`.

I can not figure it out how to do this with streams. Something like:

```
items.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(...));
```

Any help?

Here's my current code which obviously doesn't work.

```
Map<LocalDate, Integer>  values = mealList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(m->m.getDateTime().toLocalDate(),
                    m-> {/* HUH? */}));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a different `Collector`:

```
Map<LocalDate, Integer>  values = mealList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                 m -> m.getDateTime().toLocalDate(),
                 Collectors.summingInt(UserMeal::getCalories)));
```

*Or* you could use `Collectors.toMap` that has one more argument that tells how to merge entries.